# Titanium build error

Tags: titanium

Just trying to run a test app created in titanium and getting following errors:

```
/usr/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/longjohn/dist/longjohn.js:185
        throw e;
              ^
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at exports.validate (/home/inscripts/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/3.1.3.GA/android/cli/commands/_build.js:296:70)
    at exports.validatePlatformOptions (/home/inscripts/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/3.1.3.GA/node_modules/titanium-sdk/lib/titanium.js:443:51)
    at exports.validate (/home/inscripts/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/3.1.3.GA/cli/commands/build.js:112:9)
    at callCommandValidate (/usr/lib/node_modules/titanium/lib/cli.js:846:19)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:551:21
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:227:13
    at iterate (/usr/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:134:13)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:145:25
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:229:17
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:556:34
---------------------------------------------
    at exports.execFile (child_process.js:701:9)
    at exports.exec (child_process.js:588:18)
    at async.series.cached (/home/inscripts/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/3.1.3.GA/node_modules/node-appc/lib/android.js:86:4)
    at /home/inscripts/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/3.1.3.GA/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:486:21
    at /home/inscripts/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/3.1.3.GA/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:185:13
    at iterate (/home/inscripts/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/3.1.3.GA/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:108:13)
    at /home/inscripts/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/3.1.3.GA/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:119:25
    at /home/inscripts/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/3.1.3.GA/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:187:17
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 8
```

Need some help.

Answer (score 1):

You are using Titanium SDK 3.1.3.GA which does not support Android SDK Tools 22.6, nor does it support 64-bit Java. You should update Titanium SDK to newest version.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem.

and i tried following solution and that did work.

*try to update Node.js to the latest version and that should work.
older version of Node.js was generating this error on my machine. when i updated it to a newer version it worked for me.*

for reference you can refer following link
https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/150324/error-in-longjohnjs-when-creating-titanium-project

have look into this, may it'll help you.